# Spring: Rollback transactin in Unittest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a complex service method, that loads a lot of data from the db. Since it only reads and validates data I want to make sure

1. JPA (Hibernate) does not waste time for checking the big persistence
   context for changes.
2. No accidental changes to the data are written
   to the db.

Therefore towards the end of my service I have this code

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()
```

My unit tests have mocks for all db access, so transactioning is not an issue. (I have integration test with `@SpringBootTest` and full trx support as well.) Unfortunately the rollback statement fails in pure unit tests.

Is there an easy way to get the rollback statement just do nothing in case of a unit test?

Comment: Do you have autocomit for hibernate and what is propagation level for the method that you call?

Comment: It's a pure unit test. There is not database, hibernate, transactioning. I only want to test the inner logic of the service. The fact that everything is rolled back is just a safety/performance measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I just wrote a small component which is easy to mock:

```
@Component
public class RollBacker {

    public void setRollBackOnly() {
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    }

}
```

After all it's the singleton approach of `TransactionAspectSupport` which makes unit testing difficult here. IMHO `TransactionAspectSupport` should be a spring bean.

Answer (score -1):

Consider to use `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` instead of `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()`.

[Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

> A boolean flag that can be set to true if the transaction is effectively read-only, allowing for corresponding optimizations at runtime.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there's no `@SpringBootTest`. I don't have and in this case don't want transactioning or even a full application context. Just a plain vanilla unit test.